# Changin uid/gid of a running non-provileged process

Tags: c, linux

I need to implement an small capability system for Linux similar to Plan 9 [`cap`](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/magic/man2html/3/cap) device. Host owner (`root` in Linux) allows `user1` to impersonate `user2` writing `user1@user2@random-string` to `/dev/caphash`. Any `user1` process that knows `random-string` can change its `uid` to `user2` writing `user1@user2@random-string` to `/dev/capuse`.

On Linux, any privileged process can impersonate any unprivileged user with [`setuid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html)  system call, but I do not know any mechanism to allow horizontal impersonation. How do Linux do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serge E. Hallyn submitted [p9auth](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=127240105808790&w=4) to the Linux-kernel mailing list in April 2010, which would have provided pretty much this functionality (albeit in the last submitted form, with a slightly different interface). Unfortunately, it was not included in the Linux kernel.

The underlying security paradigm in Linux is vertical, rather than horizontal.

Privileges are separated into [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), and they can be acquired **at exec time only**. Extra privileges can be dropped at any time. In practice, you use filesystem capabilities and the `setcap` utility to give an unprivileged binary some specific capabilities whenever it is executed, regardless of the identity of the user executing it. (With Linux kernels 2.6.33 and later, it is no longer possible for any process to modify the capabilities of another running process.)

The key point to notice is that in Linux, only a privileged process (a process with the `CAP_SETUID`) can change its identity at run time.

In other words, point of **exec** is used in Linux for elevation of privileges, with the now-privileged binary changing to the specified user (and/or group and perhaps supplementary groups), dropping extra privileges. I am not aware of any mechanism that would allow an unprivileged process to change its [credentials](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) without an exec.

For the OP, this means that the Plan 9 interface (`/dev/caphash`, `/dev/capuse`) will not work. A comparable Linux interface implemented in userspace will require the exec of a binary as part of the change in credentials, but other than that, I don't know enough of OP's use cases to make any suggestion.

In-kernel, such an interface is obviously possible (as shown by the first link in this answer), just not available in the vanilla kernels.

Answer (score 0):

In linux (and in unix in general) there's a similar feature that has to do with one of the bit permissions of an executable file.  If you have an executable binary file, marked as *setuid* bit, then when you execute that file, the kernel runs that executable by setting the effective user id of the process to the owner of that file.  So the mechanism works if you have execute permissions to execute that file.  Let's suppose you want users `a`, `b` and `c` to impersonate user `d` on execution of some program.  You first create a group of  users (group `setuid_d`) in the system and put on it all the users `a`, `b` and `c`.  then you create the executable, make it belong to user `d`, and group `setuid_d`.  Once this has been done, as user `d` or as `root` make the file executable only by the group `setuid_d` and activate the set uid bit in the permissions

```
$ chgrp setuid_d program
$ chown d program
$ chmod ug+x,o-x,u+s program
$ program  # you'll be effectively user d when executing program
```

Comment: Question is more API than CLI oriented, but I will check that option too.